# Xml-RPC.Net Response Mapping with array

Tags: c#, xml, xml-rpc

I am trying to map Array response type from an XML-RPC, but I can't understand how to do it

The documentation about XML-RPC.NET library I am using is here
http://xml-rpc.net/faq/xmlrpcnetfaq-2-5-0.html

The example of response I get (int is always 0, and string contains random numbers) here:

```
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <array>
          <data>
            <value>
              <int>0</int>
            </value>
            <value>
              <string>9869117656.9552</string>
            </value>
          </data>
        </array>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

Here are my attempts in C# how to collect the response data

```
public struct try1 {
            public object[] returnstuff;
        }

public struct try2
        {
            public int returncode;
            public string token;
        }
```

But all these throw same exception:

```
CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcTypeMismatchException'
```

Additional information: response contains array value where struct expected

Can you help me figure it out how to make correct C# structure to collect response inormation?

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Data data = new Data();
            data.values = doc.Descendants("data").Select(x => new Values() {
                returncode = (int?)x.Descendants("int").FirstOrDefault(),
                token = (string)x.Descendants("string").FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToArray();

        }
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public Values[] values;
    }

    public class Values
    {
        public int? returncode;
        public string token;
    }

}
```